# MIPS branch execution order (beqz)

Tags: assembly, branch, mips

I'm having some issues understanding the order of instructions in this code. Let's say **beqz** is true and it branches to the label next, does the program end there or does label next2 also execute? Since there is no syscall to end the program.

```
add $t0,$t1,$t2

beqz $t0, next

b next2

addi $t0,$t0,2

next: 
   addi $t2,$t0,3

next2: 
    addi $t1,$t1,2
```

Comment: _"does the program end there?"_ No.  _"or does label next2 also execute?"_ Yes.

Comment: Your example has another issue: If a branch instruction immediately follows another one (`b` follows `beqz`) the result is undefined for MIPS CPUs. At least the manual for the MIPS R4000 CPU says this. Normally assemblers will implicitly add a `nop` instruction between the jumps in this case.

Comment: @Michael okay, thank you i think i got it know. after addition it goes back to beqz, checks again but now its false so it goes to next2, does addition and then goes to addition below b next2 and then ends.

Comment: @MartinRosenau thank you for the correction, this is just an example from class, you can blame my professor lol

Comment: @MartinRosenau: From my experience, when MIPS assembly is taught in academia, they tend to use simulators like SPIM or MARS. These have delayed branching disabled by default, probably to make things a little less complicated for the students.

Comment: @user2602540: After the last `addi` this program will just drop off into "nowhere" since you don't explicitly terminate the program, so it's undefined what will happen. It might exit cleanly by pure chance, or it might crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels are just a way to let you reference an address from another instruction.  They don't block execution.  Execution always continues to the next instruction regardless of whitespace or labels in the source.

Remember that asm source is just a language for getting machine code into a file; labels don't appear in the machine code.

---

Your code is weird.  You have an `addi $t0,$t0,2` right after a `b` instruction, so it can never be reached with branch-delay slots disabled. (Default for MARS/SPIM).  There's no label on it, so it's not a branch target you jump to from elsewhere.

But if you're on real MIPS with branch-delay slots (the instruction after a branch executes even if the branch is taken), then `b` in the branch-delay slot of a `beq` [leads to unpredictable behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234102/mips-branch-execution-order-beqz#comment89493736_51234102).  i.e. the `b` would run whether or not the branch was taken, making it pointless.  So your code doesn't make sense either way.

---

You're making your `if` much more complicated that it needs to be (or is it an `if/else`?).  **Instead of `beq` / `b` to always jump somewhere, simply use `bne` to jump or fall through.**  Also, use meaningful label names.

```asm
 ## MIPS without branch-delay slots

    add  $t0, $t1,$t2
    bnez $t0, sum_nonzero

    # addi $t0,$t0,2     # was unreachable, or was that supposed to be a branch-delay slot?

# sumzero:               # not really a branch target, only reached via fallthrough
    addi $t2, $zero, 3   # only reached with t0 = 0, might as well not even read it

    # execution falls through to the next instruction like always
sum_nonzero: 
    addi $t1,$t1,2       # runs whether bnez was taken or not

    ... execution continues
```

Or on MIPS **with branch-delay slots**, assuming that `addi $t0,$t0,2` was supposed to run only if `$t0` was non-zero.

I'm filling the branch-delay slot with the `addi $t1,$t1,2` from the fall-through path, because it always ran in your original source.  I assume that was intended.

```
    add  $t0, $t1,$t2
    bnez $t0, sum_nonzero
    addi $t1,$t1,2       # branch-delay: runs whether bnez was taken or not

# Fall through when sum == zero
    addi  $t2, $zero, 3
    addiu $t0,$zero, -2     # instead of branching to avoid addi  $t0,$t0,2 on this path, do its inverse

sum_nonzero: 
    addi  $t0,$t0,2         # produces $t0 = 0 if $t1+$t2 == 0, otherwise $t0 = $t1+$t2+2

    ... execution continues
```

If you're making an `if`/`else`, you can put the code for one side somewhere else (after the `jr $ra` return) so you don't have to jump over it.  So one path has a single not-taken branch; the other side has a taken `beq` and an unconditional `b` to rejoin the other path.

Comment: Well i'm more than a year late, but thanks for the help. The code wasn't written by me so blame my professor for the weirdness.

Comment: @user2602540: feel free to send your professor a link to this answer :P

Answer (score 0):

The program will continue with next2. I assume you want to skip next2 when the branch is true, so you can do as follows to fix it:

```
add $t0,$t1,$t2

beqz $t0, next

b next2

addi $t0,$t0,2

next: 
   addi $t2,$t0,3
   b cont

next2: 
    addi $t1,$t1,2

cont:
    # The rest of your program ...
```